# Asynctask is not updating the progress

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to display dialog progress when i extract something. But my code does the work but it does not update the progress :(. This is my code

**The main Code**

```
 class Install_Web extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute(); 
                    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        copyAssets();
                        String zipFile = server_Runner.getHttpDirectory() + "/www/www (2).zip"; 
                        String unzipLocation = server_Runner.getHttpDirectory() + "/"; 

                        Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation);
                        d.unzip(); 

                       publishProgress((int)((ze.getName().length()*100)/ze.getSize()));
}

                     catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... m) {
                    pDialog.setProgress((m[0]));
               }

                /**
                 * After completing background task
                 * Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {

                    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


                    }
            }
```

Progress Dialog

```
    @Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                switch (id) {

                case progress_bar_type :
                    // we set this to 0
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Installing file. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setMax(100);
                    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                    return pDialog;
                default:
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

The Extractor Code:

```
  public class Decompress { 
          private String _zipFile; 
          private String _location; 

          public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
            _zipFile = zipFile; 
            _location = location; 

            _dirChecker(""); 
          } 

          public void unzip() { 
            try  { 
              FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
              ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
              while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

                if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
                  _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
                } else { 
                  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
                  for ( c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
                    fout.write(c); 
                  } 

                  zin.closeEntry(); 
                  fout.close(); 
                } 

              } 
              zin.close(); 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
              Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
            } 





          } 

          private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
            File f = new File(_location + dir); 

            if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
              f.mkdirs(); 
            } 
          } 
        }
```

**I've not posted the code which has nothing to do with progress.. okkk**

Answer (score 0):

The unzip operation is synchronous, so even though you are running on a background thread by the time that the code gets to the publishProgress call, you've already completed the operation, so it will just post 100%.

I think you'd need to refactor your code such that inside your unzip() function you call publishProgress each iteration of the while loop, or something like that.

Comment: what do i need to do ??

Comment: You need to publish progress updates as they happen, not after they are finished. I would change the unzip function so that You can call publishProgress from within the while loop.